# How to create a link tag dynamically with onclick event attribute in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to make Href tag in php like this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

    echo"<a href >".$row['loginname']."<br>"."</a> ";

}
```

which retrieve the data from MySQL

I'm trying to add `Onclick` action to print `$row['loginname']`

I tried to make this one

```
echo"<a href onclick=\"myFunction()\">".$row['loginname']."<br>"."</a> ";

function myFunction()
  {

    echo " Hello";
  }
```

but It didn't work for me ? any help ?

Comment: `onclick` refers to a JavaScript event. It is not for PHP. PHP runs in the server and the user only gets the output. It does not run in the client.

Comment: Is `myFunction()` really declared within your PHP, or did you just do it that way for brevity in the question?  If so, that won't work.  You would need to print the Javascript function or put it in a file that you include in your page.

Comment: I got your message and solved my problem , thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming my comment is accurate, you would need to print the JavaScript to the page.

```
echo "<a href onclick=\"myFunction()\">".$row['loginname']."<br>"."</a> ";
$js = '<script type="text/javscript">';
$js .= 'function myFunction() { alert("hello"); }';
$js .= '</script>';
echo $js;
```

Notice I removed `echo`, as that is not JavaScript.  You can look into something like [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
     <a href="" onclick="fetchdata('<?php echo  $row['loginname']; ?>');"><?php echo  $row['loginname']; ?></a>
<?php
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var name;
   function fetchdata(name){
    alert(name);
   }

</script>
```

You can use jquery ajax method to fetch further values from mysql database